# How to connect to unusually spaced PCB edge?

Tags: connector

I have a TI-84 keypad for the TI-Nspire calculator and I thought it might be interesting to use it in a project as a button matrix. The connector looks like this:

[image: Connector]

Unfortunately the edge connector has a weird pin spacing - it's a little less than 1.4mm. I can't find any suitable connectors on DigiKey, Mouser, or anywhere else.

How can I connect to this board? I could of course just solder wires to each pin but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Hi - Is it possible that the "little less than 1.4mm" spacing is really 1.27mm? Considering the age of the calculator, I'd expect an imperial spacing, and 1.27mm is 1/20 of an inch. At least that *might* be easier to search for regarding edge connectors, rather than searching in mm. You could measure the distance for 20 of the contacts, and see if it is exactly 1 inch. Just a thought...

Comment: No, it is close to 1.39mm. I did have some 2.54mm pins on hand and if it was 1.27mm those would line up with every other pin. It is very close though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a PCB with pads that are similarly spaced and solder EMI fingers or pogo pins to them. Though then you have to solve how to mechanically support the cards.

Comment: Or you can get a flex PCB made that does the same thing, except it flexes. Would be more convenient and easier to solder than discrete wires.

Comment: I still like the (solid) PCB idea - with conductive foam, as used to connect LCDs to PCBs

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pcb of the appropriate pitch with castellated mounting holes. They allow a pcb to be directly soldered to a flat pad underneath them. They look like normal plated vias that have been chopped in half. [Castellated Mounting Holes](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-solder-castellated-mounting-holes/all)